# "Generate Signed APK" option is not display in android studio Build menu

Tags: android-studio, apk

"Generate Signed APK" option is not display in android studio  Build menu,
What is the problem or something I missed to install?? Thanks

[image]

When I click "Build APK(s)" , the android studio is no response

Comment: from file try sync project with gradle file and clean your project. if this doesn't work you might need to re-import your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly check with clean > rebuild project and see that 'app' is not having "red X" icon.

[image]

Check your `gradle` that you had not configured it with release config yet.

[image]

There must be a signing config in gradle file

[image]

Comment: awesome!!!!! really thank!!!! work for me, I forgot to set 'app', I can see the "Generate Signed APK" option now!!! thx

Comment: Do make a practice for upvote/accept answer if it helps you. So that other users with same problem can easily refer to that.

Answer (score 5):

For me, clicking **File > Sync Project with Gradle File System**  solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Follow Below Steps for Nice and Easy Way:-

1. Go to Tools->Flutter->Open for editing in android studio.
   [open for editing in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT3GJ.png)
2. Choose separate window. This will open the android part of your project in separate window.
3. Wait to Gradle to finish it's build.
4. Go to Build-> Generate signed bundle/apk.
5. Follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjpaSGEmQHs&t=192s) for further process.

Thank me later..!

Answer (score 2):

in my case, one of my harddisks hard stopped working (in which I had my first project).

`File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle` menu, changing the `Gradle user home` to another folder solved the issue. the original value of it consisted path to my first project which wasn't existing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue not having the "generate signed bundle/apk" enabled in Android Studio interface and this thread helped to deduce what was my issue... I'm new to android development so I didn't know what to do at all but checking the build.gradle file I realized that there were issues with the synchronization of gradle, so I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiRfAaAw2S0), downloaded the latest version of Grandle, then went to File > Sync with Fyle System, and after the sync was completed the button appeared.... so seems like this has a direct relation to the right synchronization of gradle.