# Android Generate apk option is not visible

Tags: android-studio

I want to generate .apk of my project. To generate it I am referring below the video. But Project Structure is disabled and Generate .apk option is not visible. I have run android studio as administrator still the same and app is also not visible.

**Video link:**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYVZXqXuyoo
```

**app option is also not visible to create `.apk`**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434074/generate-signed-apk-option-is-not-display-in-android-studio-build-menu
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try using Invalidate cache and restart option from file option

Comment: I tried this. Still the same issue.

Comment: Delete build files, .idea and .gradle file and click on option make project

Comment: I am able to see the project structure option by optioning the single project at a time.

Comment: Still generate apk option is not there

Comment: I am able to get it. It was a mistake from my side. While the project is loading the options are disabled only. Once it loads completely these options will get enable.