# COULD NOT INSTALL GRADLE DISTRIBUTION FROM 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip'

Tags: java, android, gradle, installation, download

Ever since I downloaded and install Android studio, it has been displaying this message `COULD NOT INSTALL GRADLE DISTRIBUTION FROM ...` and for that reason the `BUILD APK` option is not showing. Please, how can I solve this problem, I have visited many sites and blogs including https://developpaper.com/android-studio-error-could-not-download-gradle-jar-no-cacahed-version-available-for-offline-mode/ and many more yet, it seems not to be working, please help me, I am also new to android studio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run Android Studio as administrator may solves it.
give it a try and let us know

Comment: i just tried it now,yet it shows the same message,but the BUILD APK option is not displaying,is it as a result of this?

Comment: Do you mean Build > Build bundle/APK not displayed?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434074/generate-signed-apk-option-is-not-display-in-android-studio-build-menu , may it helps you 

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, delete

> C:\Users{your_name}.gradle

Then re-open Android Studio as Administrator as @El.MENSI mentioned above